# Powershell script to check service runing eg citrix port no 1438

Tags: powershell

Looking for powershell script which can give me the status of all my citrix server. Check for that port and then send that text file mail to all admins daily. Service running or service not running mail needs to be send.

Comment: I did tried this script below http://theadminguy.wordpress.com/2009/04/30/portscan-with-powershell/ but here I'm not able to redirect it to text file. Also I would require that text file to be mailed.

Comment: Would it be suffice to see whether the citrix service is running under Windows?  Also, are you asking us to write the whole script for you or do you have something you are already working on?

Comment: Actually, I'm not much into powershell scripting, if I get any script - that would be great.